# Looking for a common term for "non-circular pipe"

Tags: terminology

In Russia, there's a special term for a pipe that is not circular in its section: "a profiled pipe" (профильная труба). There's even a Wikipedia page for it: [профильная труба](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B0). Such pipes come in a wide variety of sizes and usually have an oval, square or rectangular section ("profile" in Russian), but other kinds of sections are possible.

I wonder what is the common cover-all technical term describing "any kind of non-circular pipe".

[image]

Example of usage:

> Pervouralsk New Pipe Plant produces a range of non-circular pipes, including pipes of variable cross-section.

([Also asked on ELL SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/93589/looking-for-a-common-term-for-non-circular-pipe))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For structural purposes these are usually called [Hollow Structural Sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollow_structural_section) (HSS). For non-structural purposes *Mechanical Tubing* is often used.

In Europe the main body that deals with structural design of these is [CIDECT](http://www.cidect.com/en/), who have a series of useful design guides. The equivalent would probably be the [Steel Tube Institute](https://steeltubeinstitute.org) in the USA who also deal with non-structural components.

Comment: I'd have gone for simply "Tube" rather than "mechanical tubing". Hollow Structural Section is also a good answer. Which is better depends on the audience.